# AngularJS: How create a new directive joining existents directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like improve my current solution.

I have a big menu using <ul> and <li> tags. I need show to the user only the <li> tags that they have permission to access.

I have resolved this problem using two directives: ng-init and ng-show

```
...
<li ng-init="ok=hasPemission('item1')" ng-show="ok">
  <a href="#/Item1">Item 1</a>
</li>
...
```

I needed to use 'ng-init' to get a stable hasPermission result. I can't use `ng-show="hasPemission('item1')"` because 'hasPemission' returns a new 'promise' object and the ng-show has problem with not stable expressions ([$rootScope:infdig] infinit $digest loop).

Now, I wanted create a new directive that join this both directives. I created this one but I think that there is a way to reuse these two existents directives.

This is my new directive:

```
.directive('myPermissionShow',['$q','$animate','AccessControl',
 function ($q, $animate, AccessControl) {
  return {
   restrict:'A',
     scope: {
      resourceName: '@myPermissionShow'
     },
     link: function ($scope, $element) {
       var user = AccessControl.getLoggedUser();
       AccessControl.hasPermission(user,$scope.resourceName).then(
         function (value) {
           // I copied the line below from ngShow directive:
           $animate[value ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']($element, 'ng-hide');
         }
       );
     }
  }
}])
```

So, my html changed to:

```
...
<li my-permission-show="item1">
  <a href="#/Item1">Item 1</a>
</li>
<li my-permission-show="item2">
  <a href="#/Item2">Item 2</a>
</li>
...
```

Is there a way to create this new directive reusing the directives 'ng-init' and 'ng-show'?

Something like this:

```
!!!NOT WORKING CODE!!!
.directive('myPermissionShow',['AccessControl',
 function (AccessControl) {
  return {
   restrict:'A',
   replaceAttribute: true, /* this property does not exists... */
   template: 'ng-init="val=hasPermission(user,resourceName)" ng-show="val"',
     scope: {
      resourceName: '@myPermissionShow'
     },
     controller: function ($scope, $element) {
       $scope.hasPemission = AccessControl.hasPermission;
       $scope.user = AccessControl.getLoggedUser();
     }
  }
}])
!!!NOT WORKING CODE!!!
```

Comment: Why don't you have a property on your controller called hasPermission which is initialised to false. This value can then be updated when your promise is resolved. Then all you need is ng-show='hasPermission' - ng-init isn't required.

Comment: @GruffBunny, I have multiple menu items. Each one with your own 'resourceName' value ('item1', 'item2'). To do this, I will need resolve a big array with all resourceName at MenuController. I prefer define all resourceName along with li tag, and not at controller.

Comment: imho the model is the most important part of an angular app. Once you have the model in place, angular is so much easier to use.

Comment: @GruffBunny, primarily, thanks for your comments. I need check if I understand your first suggested solution: I can't use only ng-show='hasPermission' because I have many permissions to check. So, I need to use ng-show="hasPermission('NameOfPermission')" or ng-show="hasPermission['NameOfPermission']" or ng-show="hasPermission.NameOfPermission". Ok?

Comment: Correct - would look quite elegant with any of your suggestions e.g. hasPermissionTo.ViewAccounts, hasPermissionTo.EditAccounts etc.